# Function mallocs a pointer and reads data into it, but caller can not access it

Tags: c, windows, file, pointers

I have a specific problem: I have an issue when I try to use my own function to load file on memory.

`load_file_on_memory()` receives a filename and a pointer. It just opens the file, allocates memory dynamically for file content and fills it, and passes the pointer to the caller using `destiny` as an argument.

But I have a problem: Inside `load_file_on_memory()` function, I have success on `malloc` space for content. I can put data on pointer and get it, too.

When I try to use the pointer outside function, the caller just gets trash. I will post my code (shortly) here.

I can't understand why this happen. I am using Windows 7 with Tiny C Compiler. I don't know if that environment can cause errors.

Here's my source

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int load_file_on_buffer(char filename[], void *buffer_destiny){
    FILE *file_loaded;
    unsigned int file_size;

    file_loaded = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if(file_loaded == NULL)
        return -1;

    fseek(file_loaded, 0, SEEK_END);
    file_size = ftell(file_loaded);
    fseek(file_loaded, 0, SEEK_SET);

    buffer_destiny = (void *) malloc(file_size);

    fread((char *) buffer_destiny, file_size, 1, file_loaded);

    printf("BEGIN DEBUG FILE\n");
    printf("%s", buffer_destiny);
    printf("\n\nEND DEBUG FILE\n");

    fclose(file_loaded);

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    char *buffered_input_file;

    ///First, load input file
    if(load_file_on_buffer("test.txt", (void *)buffered_input_file) != 0)
        return -1;

    printf("Input file loaded successfully\n");
    printf("This function must print file content: \n\n");
    printf("%s", buffered_input_file);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you still want to pass the `buffered_input_file` as a parameter then this will work for you, I commented the code at some parts I believe clarification is required.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int load_file_on_buffer(char filename[], void **buffer_destiny)
{
    FILE *file_loaded;
    unsigned int file_size;

    if (buffer_destiny == NULL)
        return -1;

    *buffer_destiny = NULL; /* to check in the calling function */
    file_loaded     = fopen(filename, "r"); /* rb is no longer needed in new code */
    if(file_loaded == NULL)
        return -1;

    fseek(file_loaded, 0, SEEK_END);
    file_size = ftell(file_loaded);
    fseek(file_loaded, 0, SEEK_SET);

    *buffer_destiny = malloc(1 + file_size); /* +1 for the null terminator */
    if (*buffer_destiny == NULL)
    {
        fclose(file_loaded);
        return -1;
    }
    /* add a null terminator so the string is acceptable by printf */
    memset(*buffer_destiny + file_size, '\0', 1);

    /* you got this wrong
    *
    * fread((char *) buffer_destiny, file_size, 1, file_loaded);
    * 
    * the correct way is
    * 
    * fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t count, FILE *fp);
    * 
    * where size is the size of each element and count is the number of elements.
    */
    if (fread(*buffer_destiny, 1, file_size, file_loaded) != file_size)
    {
        free(*buffer_destiny);
        *buffer_destiny = NULL;

        fclose(file_loaded);

        return -1;
    }

    printf("BEGIN DEBUG FILE\n");
    printf("%s", (char *)*buffer_destiny);
    printf("END DEBUG FILE\n");

    fclose(file_loaded);

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *buffered_input_file;

    if (load_file_on_buffer("data.dat", (void **)&buffered_input_file) != 0)
        return -1;
    printf("Input file loaded successfully\n");
    printf("This function must print file content: \n\n");
    printf("%s", buffered_input_file);

    free(buffered_input_file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! It has solved my problem. I have a little question: **Can I remove the code for null-terminating buffer?? I am planning to load binary data, or reserving a extra-byte for buffer can help to avoid problems??? ** Sorry If I do mistakes, I am beginner.

Comment: Only if you aare going to use `printf` or any `string.h` functions, otherwise it is safe to remove it, but not only remove it, you should also `malloc(file_size)` since you don't need to reserve space for an extra byte.

Comment: Thanks. Now I can continue coding my little project :) Double-pointers and things like that always are hard to deal. My problem is officially solved.

Answer (score 4):

You are passing a parameter void* buffer_destiny. Once the function is entered, this is just a normal variable. Which you overwrite using a malloc () call. This has no effect on the calling function. Instead declare the function as

```
int load_file_on_buffer(char filename[], void **pbuffer_destiny)
```

call it as

```
void* buffered_input_file;
load_file_on_buffer("test.txt", &buffered_input_file)
```

and in the function write

```
void* buffer_destiny = malloc (...);
*pbuffer_destiny = buffer_destiny;
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer help me to solve my problem. I didn't knew that double-pointers were needed to do that. Thanks for notice me about it.

Answer (score 3):

The pointer `buffer_destiny` is a local variable in the function `load_file_on_buffer`. Changing `buffer_destiny` has no effect on the pointer `buffer_input_file` in `main`. One way to fix the problem is to `return` the pointer to `main`.

Another problem is that you're using `"%s"` to print the files content. In order for that to work, you need to properly NUL terminate the buffer. In other words, the buffer needs to be one byte bigger than the file size and a NUL terminator `'\0'` needs to be placed in that extra byte.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *load_file_on_buffer( const char *filename )
{
    FILE *file_loaded;
    unsigned int file_size;

    file_loaded = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if(file_loaded == NULL)
        return NULL;

    fseek(file_loaded, 0, SEEK_END);
    file_size = ftell(file_loaded);
    fseek(file_loaded, 0, SEEK_SET);

    char *buffer_destiny = malloc(file_size + 1);

    fread( buffer_destiny, file_size, 1, file_loaded );
    buffer_destiny[file_size] = '\0';

    printf("BEGIN DEBUG FILE\n");
    printf("%s", buffer_destiny);
    printf("\n\nEND DEBUG FILE\n");

    fclose(file_loaded);

    return buffer_destiny;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *buffered_input_file;

    ///First, load input file
    if( (buffered_input_file = load_file_on_buffer("test.txt")) == NULL )
        return -1;

    printf("Input file loaded successfully\n");
    printf("This function must print file content: \n\n");
    printf("%s", buffered_input_file);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

buffered_input_file is NULL initially in main() and passed to load_file_on_buffer() by value. buffer_destiny initially got NULL from main() but inside function after memory allocation it should behave normally as you mentioned. However buffer_destiny is a local variable not a pointer for passed variable, hence at the end of function it loses its information and buffered_input_file in main() is still NULL.